# SugarCRM quick create leads - link to access it

Tags: sugarcrm

I changed the quick create Lead layout as required in studio. But I don't know how to access the quick create form. I can access the lead create. But not the quick create one.

Can any one help me on where to find the link to access Quick create Leads.

Thanks..

Comment: I found the link for accessing quick create.
..../sugar6/index.php?module=Leads&action=QuickCreate but javascript and css not working. When I submit form values are stored in database.

Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 0):

QuickCreate forms usually are used when there is one to many or many to one relationship with other module..let's say module A is related to module B by 1-*, now you can create many B records from detail view of A module's record. The quick create form will be used now to create the B's record.

Comment: Thanks @atul.mishra

I want to edit the background colours of text boxes in the edit view. In order to make it, which files I have to edit? Can you please suggest it.